# Integer decomposition property with a partial order

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, posets, lattice-polytopes

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a convex lattice polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We say that $\mathcal{P}$ has the  *integer decomposition property* (or "is IDP") if for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha \in k\mathcal{P}\cap\mathbb{Z}^n$, there are $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k \in \mathcal{P}\cap\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $\alpha=\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_k$. IDP polytopes are a well-studied class with connections to commutative algebra, algebraic geometry, etc.

Here's a new/nonstandard notion. Let's say $\mathcal{P}$ is IDP$\leq$ if there exists a partial order $\leq$ on $\mathcal{P}\cap\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha \in k\mathcal{P}\cap\mathbb{Z}^n$, there is a **unique** multichain $\alpha_1 \leq \cdots \leq \alpha_k \in \mathcal{P}\cap\mathbb{Z}^n$ with $\alpha=\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_k$.

For example, the order polytope $\mathcal{O}(P)$ and the chain polytope $\mathcal{C}(P)$ of a poset $P$ are IDP$\leq$ where $\leq$ is the natural distributive lattice order (on order filters/antichains).

**Question**: Are there other interesting families of IDP$\leq$ polytopes?

Motivation: this property gives a canonical/algorithmic choice of decomposition for all latice points of dilates. Also then the zeta polynomial of $(\mathcal{P}\cap\mathbb{Z}^n,\leq)$ is the Ehrhart polynomial of $\mathcal{P}$.

Comment: Forgive the terrible notation.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly more general combinatorial family that satisfies this is the family of $s$-lecture hall polytopes. These can be thought of as a weighted version of order polytopes. For a reference see theorem 1 in ["Some Algebraic Properties of Lecture Hall Polytopes"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.12459) by P. Brändén, L. Solus.

In general this sort of set up is precisely the combinatorial setup underlying *standard monomial theory*. If you look at the semigroup ring of the cone over $(\mathcal P,1)$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, your condition is equivalent to asking that the set of standard monomials (those corresponding to $\mathbb z^{\alpha_1}\cdots \mathbb z^{\alpha_k}$ with $\alpha_1\le\cdots \le \alpha_k$) form a basis. This is why you will most likely see this sort of thing used in the context of Gelfand-Tseltin polytopes, polytopes from general root systems, or other situations with a representation theoretic/geometric flavor. One application I know where this gets used a lot is in construction toric degenerations of associated flag varieties, etc.

A closely related concept that leads to this situation is that of *algebras with straightening laws*. This is where one has access to a straightening rule that expresses the product of incomparable monomials as a linear combination of standard monomials. An author that has written a lot on this sort of thing is Takayuki Hibi. For example the paper ["Chain polytopes and algebras with straightening laws"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2538) discusses straightening algeba structures on chain/order polytopes.

Comment: Another very nice answer! I guess there is not exactly a name for this situation though ("the standard monomials form a basis of the semigroup ring of the cone over the polytope" is not so snappy). I also wonder if anything interesting can be said about zeta polynomials of posets beyond distributive lattices from this Ehrhart perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the family of marked order polytopes? These include the classical [Gelfand-Tsetlin polytopes](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Epeal/polynomials/gtpatterns.htm#gtpolytopes), and I think I can construct such a partial order in case of GT-polytopes.

Let $T \in kP_\lambda$, where $T$ is a GT-pattern, which is in bijection with some SSYT in $SSYT(k \lambda,m)$. We want to find a partial order, such that
$T=T_1 + \dotsb + T_k$ in a unique manner.
Well, the $T_i$ are elements in $SSYT(\lambda,m)$,
and $+$ is interpreted as concatenate-and-sort rows. So, if we take
the partial order on $SSYT(\lambda,m)$ where $T \leq T'$ iff
for each $i \leq j$, column $i$ from $T$ together with column $j$ from $T'$
form a valid SSYT when placed next to each other.

We can then find the unique decomposition $T=T_1 + \dotsb + T_k$
by letting $T_i$ be every $k$th column from $T$, starting with the $i$th one.

I think one can extend this construction to all marked order polytopes.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon this question, pardon the necropost. There exist broad families of poset polytopes generalizing order and chain polytopes. These are known to have your IDP$\le$ property.

The first are the *chain-order polytopes* introduced by [Fang and Fourier](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02232). Each such polytope is given by a partition of a poset into two subsets, the two extremal cases are the order and chain polytopes. For a concise definition of the specific non-marked(!) version I'm referring to see, for instance, Section 2 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.07397) (we use the unfortunate term "interpolating polytopes", please ignore it).

This family is further extended by the *relative poset polytopes*. Such a polytope is given by a poset $(P,<)$ and a second order $<'$ on $P$ weaker than $<$, see Definition 2.1.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.05894). Curiously enough, we explicitly state that the IDP$\le$ property is satisfied (Corollary 2.1.7). In all of these polytopes lattice points are parametrized by order ideals so ordering them is not an issue.

Now, both chain-order polytopes and relative poset polytopes have *marked* versions where one distinguishes a subset $A$ of the poset and attaches a real number to every element of $A$. Such are the Gelfand-Tsetlin polytopes and FFLV polytopes, for instance. However, I'm not sure that the IDP$\le$ property is straightforwardly generalized to this setting. The problem is that as soon as one has non-vertex lattice points uniqueness tends to fail: if $x$, $x+v$ and $x+2v$ are lattice points in $\mathcal P$ and $x$ and $x+2v$ are comparable, then one has two distinct multichains for $2x+2v\in2\mathcal P$.

In particular, I'm afraid that this causes issues with both of the earlier answers, please correct me if I'm wrong. For Per's answer already for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and $\lambda=2\omega$ the point $\begin{smallmatrix}4 && 0\\ & 2 & \end{smallmatrix}$ in $2P_\lambda$ decomposes as both $\begin{smallmatrix}2 && 0\\ & 0 & \end{smallmatrix}+\begin{smallmatrix}2 && 0\\ & 2 & \end{smallmatrix}$ and $\begin{smallmatrix}2 && 0\\ & 1 & \end{smallmatrix}+\begin{smallmatrix}2 && 0\\ & 1 & \end{smallmatrix}$. As for the $s$-lecture hall polytopes in Gjergji's answer, no order is specified but it seems natural to assume that $0$ is the minimal element. This would lead to lack of uniqueness whenever at least one $s_i>1$.