# "Cluster algebra" structure for finite distributive lattices

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, lattice-theory, cluster-algebras

Let $P$ be an $n$-element poset and $J(P)$ the distributive lattice of its order ideals (i.e., the downwards-closed sets).

For each $I\in J(P)$ let $x_I \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the indicator function of the order ideal and let $\widetilde{x}_I \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be the lift of $x_I$ where we make the last coordinate be $1$. Let $\mathcal{C}_P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be the convex cone generated by all the $\widetilde{x}_I$ for $I \in J(P)$, and consider the semigroup $S(\mathcal{C}_P) := \mathcal{C}_P \cap \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ and its semigroup algebra $k[S(\mathcal{C}_P)]$.

($\mathcal{C}_P$ is the cone of the affinization of the "order polytope" of $P$.)

---

Let us say that $I, I' \in J(P)$ are *compatible* if either $I\subseteq I'$ or $I'\subseteq I$.

**Question**: Has anyone considered the following analogy, suggesting $k[S(\mathcal{C}_P)]$ is similar to a cluster algebra? :

Clusters <-> Maximal collections of pairwise compatible elements of $J(P)$ (these are in bijection with linear extensions of $P$)

Cluster monomials <-> Monomials $\widetilde{x}_{I_1}^{i_1} \cdots \widetilde{x}_{I_m}^{i_m} \in k[S(\mathcal{C}_P)]$ with $I_1,\ldots,I_m$ pairwise compatible

Cluster mutation <-> ???

---

The point is that monomials of the form above give a basis for $k[S(\mathcal{C}_P)]$, just like for finite type cluster algebras the cluster monomials give a basis.

Comment: Something that could possibly be relevant: Higashitani showed in "Two poset polytopes are mutation-equivalent" (https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.01364) that Stanley's transfer map between the order and chain polytopes of a poset can be realized by a series of "combinatorial mutations" of polytopes (whatever that means...)

Comment: Somewhat related previous question of mine: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373256/integer-decomposition-property-with-a-partial-order

Comment: Maybe it's better to work more simply with the cone generated by the $x_I$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$; then I think the relations are $x_I x_J = x_{I \cap J} x_{I \cup J}$. In this form these are maybe what are called "Hibi rings." I think this just amounts to throwing away the empty order ideal, so shouldn't make too much of a difference.

Comment: If I understand your notations, the algebra $k[S(\mathcal C_P)]$ is actually what is more commonly known as the _Hibi ring/algebra_ and its generating relations are the ones you specify (generators of the _Hibi ideal_, a.k.a. the toric ideal of the _order polytope_ of $P$). The ring generated by the (exponentials of the) $x_I$ can have more relations.

Comment: @imakhlin I am not an expert in all this terminology, but yes I agree that the Hibi ring is at least very close to what I am talking about. I am wondering if the fact that it has a "cluster monomial" style basis has been observed/exploited anywhere, or if this analogy has been developed further. (Incidentally, I'm a bit confused about calling this a toric ideal: usually I would think the toric variety corresponding to a polytope is the *complete, projective* variety corresponding to the *normal fan* of the polytope, but the thing I'm talking about is definitely affine and not complete.)

Comment: So the $\mathrm{Proj}$ of the ring given by the relations $X_IX_J-X_{I\cap J}X_{I\cup J}$ (the Hibi ring) is the (projective, complete, normal) toric variety of the order polytope, which is the convex hull of your $x_I$. Subsequently, this ring can be realized as the ring generated by the exponentials of your $\tilde x_I$ (the semigroup ring of the cone, yes).

Comment: I'm not sure whom to credit with the fact that products over weakly increasing tuples form a basis, I'd view this as folklore of sorts. My favorite way of seeing this is that the set of all _other_ monomials span a monomial ideal which is an initial ideal of the Hibi ideal (see Proposition 2.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.02916.pdf but I'm definitely not going to take credit for this).

Comment: Just as a side note, there's a very nice and well-known example. If you consider the set of all increasing columns of integers from $[1,n]$ and order them by $I<J$ iff the corresponding two-column Young tableau is semistandard, then you obtain a distributive lattice. The set of monomials you consider is the basis in the Plücker algebra given by all semistandard tableaux.

Comment: Sure, I agree this fact is folklore, and immediate to prove once you hear it - but again I'm more asking if there is a developed connection to cluster theory since superficially it seems so similar. E.g. does anyone view the different linear extensions (clusters) as giving different "charts" on some variety, that we can pass between via "mutations" of some kind?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I understand the question, I was just trying to give a bit of context concerning Hibi ideals etc. I don't immediately recall such a connection with cluster theory being explored, no.

Comment: Your question reminds me of Lam-Pylyavsky's LP algebras. There's a special kind of LP algebras called graph LP algebras (https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2612) that can be encoded by a directed graph, where clusters are nested collections of subsets of vertices (nested means pair-wise compatible or disjoint). I don't remember a lot about order polytopes now but maybe, if G is the comparability graph of P, then the graph LP algebra of G could say something about $k[S(\mathcal{C}_P)]$.